# Troubleshooting ClassNotFoundException when using PHP/Java bridge

Tags: java, php

I've followed this tutorial http://www.dsl.uow.edu.au/~sk33/php5java.htm, but at last when I tried this

```
<?php

java_require('http://localhost/test/HelloWorld.jar');
$myObj = new Java('HelloWorld');

// display Hello World
echo (String) $myObj->getHelloWorld();


?>
```

I got this exception

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught [o(Exception):"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed:new HelloWorld. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find HelloWorld in java_require() path. Please check the path and the SEL and File permissions. Responsible VM: 1.5.0_14@http://java.sun.com/" at:#-10 php java.bridge.DynamicJavaBridgeClassLoader.loadClass(DynamicJavaBridgeClassLoader.java:293)

Comment: Is it possible to specify a filesystem path to HelloWorld.jar instead of a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you're following is 5 years old and, according to the [FAQ](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/FAQ.html), `java_require()` is deprecated:

> > **Why has java_require() been deprecated?**
> >
> > Because Java doesn't have a module system.
> >
> > For example a library "lucene-2.3.1.jar" required by application B, cannot be loaded if an older version of the library, required by application A, is already cached.
> >     **An attempt to link the library anyway will cause "NoClassDefFound" or "NoSuchMethod" errors at runtime**. Or some procedures may throw checked exceptions even though they haven't declared them.
> >
> > To protect PHP developers from Java's "jar hell", **I have removed the dynamic class loading mechanism from PHP/Java Bridge version 6.0**; java_require() issues a warning.
> >
> > A proper Java module system must use special Java VM hooks, which don't exist until now.
> >
> > **How do I load Java libraries?**
> >
> > You should link your Java application as described in the [Java standalone](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/desktop-apps.php) or [Java webapps](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/webapp.php) documents.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the `HelloWorld` class wasn't found.

Verify that the file is really located at the address you used for `java_require`. If it is, check and make sure the code in the file is exactly as described in the tutorial.