# PHP/Java Bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting ClassNotFoundException when using PHP/Java bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829265/troubleshooting-classnotfoundexception-when-using-php-java-bridge)

Can anyone please explain me about the PHP/Java Bridge installation.

I already installed bridge in my system.

This is my `HelloWorld.java` code :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT="8081";
    static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner = 
                 php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        runner.waitFor();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void hello(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello " + args[0]);
    }
}
```

This is my `HelloWorld.php` code:

```
<?php 
    require_once("http://localhost:8081/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");

    $world = new java("HelloWorld");
    echo $world->hello(array("from PHP"));
?>
```

While calling Java class from php, it is not working and it is showing the below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new HelloWorld. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld VM: 1.5.0_01@http://java.sun.com/" at: #-31 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438) #-30 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284) #-29 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) #-28 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) #-27 java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) #-26 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518) #-25 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445) #-24 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458) #-23 php.java.bridge.Request.handleOneRequest(Request.java:510) #-22 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handleLocalConnection(PhpJavaServlet.java:202) #-21 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handlePut(PhpJavaServlet.java:250) #-20 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.doPut(PhpJavaServlet.java:261) #-19 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpS in http://localhost:8081/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

Can you please anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the package you are trying to use but it looks like you need to give the full path to your class. That is `java/lang/ClassNotFoundException` for example for the Java Exception that is being thrown and probably something like `me/mypackage/HelloWordl` for the class you are trying to create.