# OpenShift php java bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I use 'PHP 5.4 with Zend Server 6.1' Cartridges in OpenShift.
I need use java bridge.

index.php

```
<?php
java_require('./Test.jar');
$java = new java('com.lanyus.Test');
echo $java->Get();
```

Test.java

```
package com.lanyus;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.printf("Test");
    }

    public String Get() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JavaException' with message
>   'Java Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lanyus.Test java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lanyus.Test at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) ' in /var/lib/openshift/55dcc55f89f5cf3459000240/app-root/runtime/repo/php/test/index.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/lib/openshift/55dcc55f89f5cf3459000240/app-root/runtime/repo/php/test/index.php(9):
>   *No Class!*->jbridge('com.lanyus.Test') #1 {main} thrown in /var/lib/openshift/55dcc55f89f5cf3459000240/app-root/runtime/repo/php/test/index.php
>   on line 9

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here; the wording is a little unclear. It sounds like you're trying to figure out what's causing the error described by the stack trace. Have you made sure that the JAR is in the location specified by `java_require`? This looks like you just have the wrong path string.

Comment: index.php and Test.jar is  in a directory

Comment: java_require('/var/lib/openshift/55dcc55f89f5cf3459000240/app-root/runtime/repo/php/test/Test.jar') is Fatal error,too.

Comment: I'm almost positive that this is an issue with the path to the jar. I think it's relative to some directory setting in Java Bridge by default, and using HTTP as a fallback. I just can't figure out where to find the default directory that java_require is relative to.

Comment: Yes.I exec 'env' command by ssh,but no JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH.

Comment: I exec 'find ~/zend -name "*.ini" | xargs grep "java" ' ,but no file to set the path to the jar.

Comment: Okay, try reading up on what you find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829265/troubleshooting-classnotfoundexception-when-using-php-java-bridge

Comment: Sorry,I found the issue,because of git no auto Add,so sorry.

Comment: The php file is auto add ,but the jar file not is.Sorry.